# Improving throughput of a Node.js REST API client using Worker Threads

Tags: node.js, multithreading, worker

Everything I have read suggests that Node 'Worker Threads' are most applicable to CPU-intensive code and that asynchronous is more efficient for I/O in Node.js.

I have a potential application for Workers in Node.js that, although I/O related, I believe may be more effective to implement with Workers.

The scenario is iterating and fetching a list of resources from a server REST API. The currently asynchronous implementation is inherently single-threaded even though the server can support multiple simultaneous requests.

It seems that the throughput could be improved with Workers by allowing parallel requests to the server rather than serializing the requests.

Is this an appropriate use of Node.js Worker Threads?

Comment: Sure, why not? There is no "strict" definition what to put in worker threads.

Comment: Yes, I agree with no "strict" definition, and "why not" sentiment.  I'm just wondering if there is anything I'm overlooking since this will be my first use of worker threads.